# How to remove an item from database populated dropdown box

Tags: php, mysql

Below is my code so far.

```
<?php

$con=mysql_connect('localhost','root') or die ("Server connection failure!");
$db=mysql_select_db('regional_data',$con) or die ("Couldn't connect the database");
$SQL="SELECT sbstart, sbend FROM newchk";
$run=mysql_query($SQL,$con) or die ("SQL Error");
$nor=mysql_num_rows($run);

echo "<select STYLE='width:230px'>";
while ($rec = mysql_fetch_array($run))
{
for($i=$rec['sbstart']; $i<=$rec['sbend']; $i++)
{
echo "<option>$i<br></option>";
}
}
echo "</select>";
?>
```

this is the database:
+--------+----------+
|sbstart | sbend    |
|***_*__*_*__*_*__**|
|  200   | 205      |
|  400   | 405      |
|        |          |

Infront of the dropdown I have "Save" button which expects to save the number choosen from the dropdown by the user along with another text field input. Once this is done what I need is the chosen number by the user has to be taken away from the drop down so another user selecting the dropdown wouldn't see tht number. (The database has only the starting and ending number however dropdown will populate all the numbers in between.)

Example : Database has two data rows for each starting and ending number. starting numbers are 200, 400 and ending numbers are 205, 405. If a user selects 202 option from the dropdown and saves the same next time dropdown should appear 202 in the list. Thats what I need. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Warning: The `mysql_xx()` functions are considered obsolete. The PHP manual **strongly** recommends switching to use either the equivalent `mysqli_xx()` functions or the PDO library.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add [`value`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_option_value.asp) attribute to `option` tag to get it in `$_POST` array. In your example: `'<option value="'.$i.'">'`

If you have form:

```
<form action="script.php" method="post">
    <select name="myName">
       <option value="0">0</option>
       <option value="1">1</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

When you submit this form you can get it's value: `$_POST['myName']`

**Note:** Forgive me for giving link to w3schools. It was what google showed first.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. would you mind explaining a bit more on how should I code that 'Save' button to get the desired output. Sorry I'm still a learner!

Comment: @MohanWijesena Because you are a beginner I'd advice you never ask for code, ask for things using what you can do actual thing or if you get stuck and can't understand why, ask: "Why?" When you start working (if you actually don't) nobody will write code for you. I'll update my answer to give you a little example.

Comment: Thanks and agreed! What I dont understand is the concept of assigning 'values' to the option since the list items are auto loaded from the database. If I have fixed values as in your example 0,1, ... yes I'm aware than a value can be assigned. I hope u get where Im stuck at. Thanks again

Comment: @MohanWijesena simply add `value='$i'` in `option` tag in generation code.